# How do I apply for a permit for the Zona de Reserva in Parque Natural Sierra de Grazalema? Can it be done online?

Tags: hiking, preparation, spain, permits

Within [Parque Natural Sierra de Grazalema](http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/medioambiente/servtc5/ventana/mostrarFicha.do), is the *Zona de Reserva*, for which special permits are required:

> *The Spanish fir forest and other areas in the Reserve can only be visited at certain times of the year, and visitor numbers are limited, so you are advised to get information in advance.*

According to the [Spanish Wikipedia article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parque_natural_de_la_Sierra_de_Grazalema), the Centro de Visitantes (visitor centre) in El Bosque serves for obtaining authorisation to access de *Zona de Reserva*:

> Centro de Visitantes de El Bosque. C/Fco. García Lorca s/n. 11670, El Bosque. Tfno.: 956709733. Este centro realiza las funciones de central para la obtención de autorización de acceso a la Zona de Reserva.

And according to [Sierra de Grazalema: Complete Guidebook to the Natural Park](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sierra-Grazalema-Complete-Guidebook-Natural/dp/8493565385), reservations must be made between 1 and 30 days in advance and are limited to 20 people per day.  The guidebook lists a telephone number (which is different from the one on Wikipedia or the park website) that I have not tried to phone yet, but in my experience the English language knowledge of visitor centre employees can be very limited (and my Spanish is poor).

How do I apply for a permit to visit the Zona de Reserva in the Parque Natural Sierra de Grazalema?

Comment: What time of year are you planning on going?

Comment: @Ian Early January

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phone number is right: + 34 956 70 97 33 (Grazalema's park visitors centre, El Bosque)

You can send an email to this address:

cv_elbosque@agenciamedioambienteyagua.es

In this mail, you must provide:

1. Passport number.
2. Number of persons.
3. Date of the visit.
4. Trail to follow (read below, the restricted area you want to visit).

Restricted areas are:

- Pinsapar.
- Llanos de Ravel: http://www.buscamapas.com/maps/hiking-trails/Llanos-del-Rabel
- Torreón (highest Cadiz county peak): http://www.buscamapas.com/maps/hiking-trails/Ascension-al-Torreon-Techo-prov-Cadiz
- Garganta Verde.

Comment: I forgot to post it here as an answer, but ultimately I obtained a permit by e-mailing `pn.grazalema.cmaot@juntadeandalucia.es.` with the indicated information.  Judging from the number of people on the trail, I must conclude that the majority hikes without a permit.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out that you can book visits online (only spanish language):

http://www.reservatuvisita.es/reservas/1248/el-bosque.html

In main page (www.reservatuvisita.es) you can find visitor centers in natural areas of Andalusia (spanish southern region)

Best regards!

Comment: That appears to be for guided tours, not just for permits, right?  Permits are free of charge and that page asks €8.